# Compass unable to find files in project

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass, codekit

I am editing the a wordpress template that makes use of SASS. When I edit the .scss file and save it, CodeKit throws out this error.

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project: 

error app.scss (Line 9 of _settings.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.
Load paths:
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/ecpr_sgoc/scss
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/bourbon/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/neat
  /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/susy/sass
  Compass::SpriteImporter)
identical app.css 


(This action was triggered by a change to _colors.scss)
```

**EDIT:** I just upgraded to CodeKit 2 and this is the new output:

```
Compass failed to run because your Mac has an older version of Sass and/or Compass
installed that conflicts with the newer versions in CodeKit. You must remove all
versions of Sass below 3.3.rc6 and all versions of Compass below 1.0.alpha18.
Do this at the command line by running 'sudo gem uninstall sass'
and 'sudo gem uninstall compass'.
```

But I have Sass 3.3.4 and Compass 0.12.5 (which, AFAIK, is more recent than the mentioned 1.0.alpha18) installed...

Comment: I haven got any experince with CodeKit. Did you install all the required gems for the project (e.g. blueprint). And did you check if all files are present (and readable for CodeKit) at the paths mentioned in your error report?

Comment: Yes, I checked, but all the folders that Compass is unable to find are actually there...

Comment: OK. I don't know how it is on Mac, but on Linux you also have to be sure that the user running CodeKit is able to read the files and folders. If that also goes for Mac, check the permissions too.

Comment: I upgraded to CodeKit 2 but still no solution. I edited the opening post with the new error text, tho.

Comment: I think 1.0.alpha18 is the bleeding edge branch of Compass as where the 0.12.5 is the stable version. It is true that (seen in time) the stable version is more recent, but I think these are separate paths in releases. Isn't there some option in CodeKit, where you can tell CodeKit only to use stable releases of the libraries you're using?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find it unfortunately.

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.zacharybrady.com/getting-compass-modules-to-work-with-codekit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to remove any old version of sass and compass like so :

sudo gem uninstall sass, sudo gem uninstall compass

ex:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall sass

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. sass-3.2.19
 2. sass-3.3.5
 3. All versions
```

and just keep only the newest version of sass and compass and codekit will work like charm :)

I solved my Problem with this