# Valid SCSS not compiling with Codekit

Tags: sass, compass-sass, codekit

I'm having trouble with codekit, the code below is correct and should work with sass 3.4.5 (selective steve) which is running with my codekit 2.1.6 - ive tested the code with sassMeister and have provided a link. Has anyone got an idea what is going on?

Codekit was setup as a compass project using the latest compass.

Codekit gives me:

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project: 

    error style.scss (Line 3 of _nav.scss: Invalid CSS after "  &": expected "{", was "__list {"

"__list" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.)
identical style.css
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/f07191a09789e354bae6

```
nav[role=navigation] {color: black;}
.nav {
  &__list {
    color: black;
    &__item {
      color: black;
    }
  }
  &__link {
    color: black;
    &--active {
      color: black;
    }
  }
}
```

should convert to

```
nav[role=navigation] {
  color: black;
}

.nav__list {
  color: black;
}
.nav__list__item {
  color: black;
}
.nav__link {
  color: black;
}
.nav__link--active {
  color: black;
}
```

**EDIT**
if I go about in codekit its using SASS 3.4.5 and Compass 0.12.7 (which is the current) - ill try to installl a later version of compass

**IF I RUN COMPASS WATCH ON THE DIRECTORY IT WORKS but Codekit doesnt..**

**EDIT**

Codekit seems to be using an older version of Compass - even if I point it to my locally installed version.

**EDIT**

I believe that the version of compass codekit is using on my system is too old - 0.12.7 where it needs to run 1.0.1 - but I cant find out how to get it to switch

Comment: Are you certain you're using Compass 1.0+?  The syntax you're using is a feature of Sass 3.3+, but Compass 0.12  would force you into using Sass 3.2.

Comment: if I go about in codekit its using SASS 3.4.5 and Compass 0.12.7 (which is the current) - ill try to installl a later version of compass

Comment: No, the current version of Compass is 1.0.1 (see: http://rubygems.org/gems/compass/)

Comment: Ok, if i do compass -v in the terminal I get 1.0.1 but codekit is reporting its using 0.12.7

Comment: This *should* solve your problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895961/compass-unable-to-find-files-in-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codekit didnt seem to pick up the correct version of compass - no documentation, so I moved back to the terminal.